# Does Poisoner Feat work on Warlock Familiars?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, familiars, poison

If a player is a [Pact of the Chain Warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#PactoftheChain) and they decide to choose their familiar to be a [sprite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17020-sprite) and had the [Poisoner Feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/feats#Poisoner), could they use that feat to apply poison to the sprite's weapons?

Comment: I’ve added the D&D 5e tag since you mentioned Pact of the Chain warlocks. Let us know if this is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, you can poison someone else's weapon

There is nothing in the feat that says it has to be the character's weapon, just "a weapon".

However, the first bullet point of the feat states, "When **you** make a damage roll that deals poison damage, it ignores resistance to poison damage", so the sprite will not get that benefit as it is tied directly to the character with the feat.

Comment: If the Warlock's sprite familiar has the poisoner's feat applied to their shortbow would the 3rd feature of that same feat and the other affect of the sprite's shortbow cause a creature to make two separate save throws?

Comment: @ChampionofUbtao, that's kind of a separate question, but to save you time, it's already been asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136174/38834) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196004/38834). Basically, unless your DM rules otherwise, poisons won't stack. So it's just one poison or another.